# Where are my assets files stored?

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

As I have read, Heroku recommends pointing your CDN directly at your dynos rather than using asset_sync, therefore I did this:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.action_controller.asset_host = "<MY DISTRIBUTION SUBDOMAIN>.cloudfront.net"
```

The origin of my distribution is `dcaclab.com`
The CNAMEs of my distribution is `assets.dcaclab.com`

So, after I successfully pushed my rails 4 app to heroku, I found that all my assets are served from my cloudfront's distribution, like:

```
http://<MY DISTRIBUTION SUBDOMAIN>.cloudfront.net/assets/features/Multiple%20Circuits-edbfca60b3a74e6e57943dc72745a98c.jpg
```

What I don't understand, is how my assets files got uploaded to the my cloudfront's distribution?! also, where I can find them?
I thought they would be uploaded to my s3 bucket `assets` but it was just empty.

Can some enlighten me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your files are being served from your CloudFront distribution and they are not being pulled from your S3 bucket "assets" as you previously thought, then you probably have set up your CloudFront distribution to use a custom origin such as your web server (S3 buckets are the normal/standard origins).

If you have set up your CloudFront distribution to use your web server as the origin, then CloudFront will pull the files from your web server before caching them on different edge locations (the pulling and caching is automatically done by CloudFront when a user access resources through the "distributionname.cloudfront.net" domain).

By the way, just a side note, I ran "dig assets.dcaclab.com" which resolves to "assets.dcaclab.com.s3.amazonaws.com".

Comment: I can get my s3 stored files served through distribution point, but I can notice that the file is downloaded each time, its not cached, is there something I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

If I read [the intro docs](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) correctly; you don't necessarily see them on Cloudfront, at least not outside of the management console. They're cached on edge nodes, and requested from your Origin if they're not found or expired. They're "uploaded" on-demand; the edge requests the file from the origin if it doesn't have it.

Comment: That's really cool, but won't I have to provide any credentials?! I mean, how would I prevent others to use my cloudfront distribution? as I will be billed for this service.. ? its as simple as config.action_controller.asset_host= "<MY DISTRIBUTION SUBDOMAIN>.cloudfront.net", right?

Comment: That was only my understanding of it; I could be wrong. I recommend you read the link to intro docs I shared, as well as this Heroku DevCenter guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-amazon-cloudfront-cdn

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I can control it by setting the origin in the distribution point, setting it to custom (my website) or s3 bucket